# How to configure the port to be used by the AJP connector and the JMX connector

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, jboss

Which file to edit to configure the port to be used by the AJP connector and the JMX connector, for tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

For the AJP connector, define it in /conf/server.xml, the default configuration follows:

```
    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

For jmx-port, add it to the java_opts at startup in catalina.sh:

`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9004`